# Decrement the column value by 1 before finding that value in array (MySql WHERE Condition)

Tags: mysql

I want to decrement the column value by 1 before finding that value in array.

```
select * 
from tbl_credit 
where int_credit in (12, 13, 14, 15)

int_credit=13
```

But I want to decrement int_credit by 1 as like below

```
select * 
from tbl_credit 
where 12 in (12, 13, 14, 15)
```

Can I implement the logic in this query?

Comment: Have you tried `select * from tbl_credit where int_credit-1 in (12, 13, 14, 15)`

Comment: sql does not have the concept of arrays,

Comment: Why isn't my hammer working?